# Random behavior in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, date-format

```
echo $form->input('birthday', array(
    'label' => 'Birthday',
    'type' => 'date',
    'dateFormat' => 'MDYMDY',
    'value' => $bday,
    'empty'=>false,
    'minYear'=>1900,
    'maxYear'=>$max_year-12
));
```

I have a user, whose birthday is 3/5/81 (m/d/y). It is stored as a unix timestamp. This is what is displayed:

http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/5946/ss20110620040305.png

Notice my code - MDYMDY

If I use only MDY - it displays June 5 1999. However, MDYMDY displays June 5, 1999 and Mar 5, 1981.

Am I missing some random code snippet?

Comment: 'Multiple exclamation marks,' he went on, shaking his head, 'are a sure sign of a diseased mind.' -- Terry Pratchett on _Eric_

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós but he stopped at 2!

Comment: I'm curious as to why you have that format for a birthday in the first place. Why are you selecting two dates?

Comment: I'm not selecting two dates, I just want to display the correct date based on the timestamp I pass through. Random trial/error found that behavior.. It tells me I am passing the right value because the second set of dates are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `dateFormat` and `type` - if your field is datetime, it will automatically output the format you're hoping for.

You can also remove `empty`, since that's defaulted to false.  And lastly, you shouldn't need to set `value` - if it's set up correctly, this will be populated by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of interest, have you tried changing the format to MDY and then hitting CTRL + F5?

Sometimes I find Combos don't change value unless they're forced.